# how do I generate a tag cloud in acts_as_taggable_on?

Tags: tags, tag-cloud, acts-as-taggable-on-ster

I can't debug why I am getting an error:

```
class VendorsController < ApplicationController
  def tag_cloud
    @tags = Vendor.tag_counts_on(:tags)
  end
```

I set this class as Taggable:

```
class Vendor < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_taggable_on :tags, :competitors
```

I include the TagsHelper:

```
module VendorsHelper
  include TagsHelper
end
```

This is in my View:

```
 <% tag_cloud(@tags, %w(css1 css2 css3 css4)) do |tag, css_class| %>

    <%= link_to tag.name, { :action => :tag, :id => tag.name }, :class => css_class %> 

<% end %>
```

This is the error that I get:

```
You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of Array.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.empty?
```

Each instance of Vendor has at least one Tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got it, I needed to add: `@tags = Vendor.tag_counts_on(:tags)` in the `index controller`.